# How to get the document id which consists that collection while making collection group query?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am making a collection group query and getting the data by .get method , is there any way to get the document id which consists that collection ?

Collection:Users ------ Doccument:user1 ->  Collection:Posts -> Document:post 1,2,3..
------- Doccument:user2 -> Collection: Posts ->
Document:post a,b,c..

So while making the query i am getting post 1,2,3.. & a,b,c..

But how to get the document document id from where a,b,c or 1,2,3 are comming ?

In this case it i want to get user 1 & user 2 as result !

Just let me know if it is possible first !

- Android : Kotlin

Comment: Show us the code that reads all those documents and tell where do you need to read the document ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a document of any of the `Posts` subcollections you need to:

- Firstly, get the [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference) of the Document's parent Collection, with the [`getParent()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#getparent) method of the [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference)
- Secondly, on this parent `CollectionReference`, call the [`getParent()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#getparent) method which returns the `DocumentReference` of the Collection's parent Document.
- Finally, use the [`getId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#getid) method on this `DocumentReference`. You're done.

Comment: ok got it ! will these methods result in read count by +1 of the database ? whenever I use .getParent() or getId()  ?

Comment: No there is no cost: you are just calling methods of References and not fetching/reading documents.

Comment: what if I fetch the document fields after getting the doc id by getId() method as you have mentioned in 3rd point , will it be considerd as 1 read count ?

Comment: I think it will be  , thank you so much for the answer !