# Can not read firebase collection with user id with Flutter web, while there is not problem on mobile flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have flutter mobile and flutter web using same firebase firestore. But somehow I can not read all data from web.

```
final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(_allReports);      
print('* * * allReports - ${(await collection.get()).docs.length}');
```

on output 0, while there is a two item showed on above screen shot.
I had some experience, if I create item with random symbols instead of user id, it works. And if try to get reports by providing whole path 'all_reports/user_id/reports/' it works also.

[image: firebase]

Rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isUserAuthenticated();
    }
    match /all_reports/{document=**} {
        allow read: if true;
    }
    
    /* Functions */
    function isUserAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth.uid != null; 
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone solve this?

Comment: Going forward, please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content (such as your security rules). Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Look at how your documents are displayed in an italic font: This means that these documents are only present as "container" of one or more sub-collection but that they are not "genuine" documents.

They are shown in the Firestore console (in italic) for you to be able to open the subcollection (i.e. `reports`) but they actually don't exist, hence the value of `0` for `docs.length` (the `QuerySnapshot` returned by the query is empty).

And this also explains why you get a non empty `QuerySnapshot` when you query the subcollection with the following path:  `all_reports/user_id/reports/`.

If you want to query the `all_reports` collection you need to create the corresponding documents. But are you sure you need to query this collection?

---

**Update following your comment:**

> I want to get all reports of all users

You can use a [Collection Group query.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query): A Collection Group consists of all collections with the same ID (i.e. `reports` in your case).

Note that if you need the user's uid for each report (i.e. the "fake" parent document), you can use the approach explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73389623/3371862), i.e. getting the parent ref of the report document (it is the `reports` subcollection for the user) and then the parent document of this subcollection.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
It is easier than I thought.

```
final groupReportCollections = fb.collectionGroup(_reports);
groupReportCollections.get().then((value) 
=> value.docs.forEach((e) => log('item: ${e.data()}')));
```