# How can i save my data in Firestore as collection instead of collection group

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner in development and am trying to develop a basic app
The problem i'm encountering is that i'm saving data in firestore as collection but it is being saved as collection group

This is how my data is being saved according to me

/Users(collection)/username(doc)/Personalinformation(subcollection)/PhysicalInfo(doc)/{data}

using the following code

```
final parentCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users");
          parentCollection.doc(usernamecontroller.text).collection ("PersonalInformation").doc("infoData").set(
            {
              "firstname":"N/A",
              "lastname":"N/A",
              "DOB":"N/A",
              "isRegistered":false,
              "BMR":"N/A",
              "height":"N/A",
              "weight":"N/A",
              "gender":"N/A",
              "email":"N/A",
            }

           );
```

now i want to check if a user exists or not using snapshot.exists method

```
InkWell(
  child: Text("Check Document Existence"),
  onTap: () async {
    final String documentId = "sobantest"; // Replace with the document ID you want to check

    try {
      final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(documentId)
          .get();

      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print("Document Exists");
      } else {
        print("Document does not exist");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error checking document existence: $e");
    }
  },
)
```

but the problem i'm getting is that it always returns that document does not exist even tho it exists

then i checked the query builder and found that the document is appearing in collection group but not in collection

is it possible to save it as collection so i can user above code

also if possible let me know the difference and is it alright to use collection group instead of collection considering i want to use a single collection for all users

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "the document is appearing in collection group"?

Comment: I mean the query scope. when collection is selected docs i created don't appear but when query scope is selected as collection group the docs are listed as intended

Comment: the collection group is selected as PersonalInformation. but main problem i'm encountering is that i'm unable to check if the doc exists or not

Comment: Are you 100% sure the user doc exists? Did you create it with another piece of code (note that the code in your question **does not** create a user doc)? Does it appears in italic in the console (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76446334/3371862)?

Comment: Yes it's Italic in the console.